# Dynamics CRM Provisioning Options

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, provisioning, mps

Our business is looking to automating Dynamics CRM hosting. We've been looking at the options. At the moment, it seems like HMC/MPS would be useful. However, from the looks of it, the frameworks are nearing end of life and are also. HMC/MPS also seems to be based around exchange.  Would it make sense to use HMC/MPS to provision CRM or is there another framework. Would we be better off talking directly with the Active Directory and CRM Deployment Service APIs?

Answer (score 1):

I work for EMS-Cortex and this is what we do. Please have a look at our website www.ems-cortex.com and if you are interested get in touch.

Please remember HMC/MPS has been cancelled, and if you invest in it now you are investing in technology which will have disappeared in about 12 months.

Kind Regards

Daniel Thurston